# How can I prevent my furnace exhaust pipe from freezing?

Tags: hvac, furnace

My furnace keeps on turning off because my air intake freezes. The reason it freezes up is because my neighbors exhaust vent blows directly on it. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: There are codes about how far apart furnace air intakes and exhausts must be.  Depending on wording, it may regulate the distance between the outlet of a furnace and the intake of ***any*** furnace...

Comment: Which was installed later, your intake or their exhaust?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the pipe along the outside wall away from the neighbor's vent to prevent it from causing the freeze.

you can also have the neighbor's vent extended away from your pipe depending on what is easier/how willing your neighbor is.

the separation can be as easy as hanging a piece of plywood to redirect his air away.